# electron: preload script not executed in about:blank iframes

Tags: electron

According to Electron documentation when BrowserWindow or Webview is created with option `nodeintegrationinsubframes` then specified preload should be executed in every iframe.

But defined preload script is executed in all iframe **except "about:blank" iframes**.
(iframe without defined src attribute).

Is it bug? Is there any work-around?

I have tested if other options like `nodeIntegration` or `contextIsolation` has some impact to this, but it has not.

From Documentation
`nodeIntegrationInSubFrames`
*A `Boolean` for the experimental option for enabling NodeJS support in sub-frames such as iframes inside the `webview`. All your preloads will load for every iframe, you can use `process.isMainFrame` to determine if you are in the main frame or not. This option is disabled by default in the guest page.*

- [Webview](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag/#nodeintegrationinsubframes)
- [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window/#new-browserwindowoptions)

There is [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/jirisliva-nw/4e58430964de0370ea4cfd9189184194) to reproduce issue in [Electron Fiddle](https://www.electronjs.org/fiddle).

Comment: Hi, any update on this question?